# Two input elements return the same ID on focus event

Tags: jquery

I have two inputs with different IDs. When the focus event handlers fire both inputs appear to have the same ID. Other events such as blur do not exhibit this problem. This is my stripped back code to illustrate the issue. `event.target.id` returns the same values. What is happening here?

```js
$('#first, #second').focus(function() {
  id = this.id;
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="text"><br/>
<input id="second" type="text">
```

EDIT

This minimal example exhibits my problem

```
HTML
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-gb"><head>
</head>
<body>
<?php include "../php/main/printopp.php"; ?>
<script src="../js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/printopp.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

PHP
<?php
echo '<input id="first" type="text">';
echo '<input id="second" type="text">';

JQUERY
$('#first, #second').focus(function(event) {
  id = this.id;
  console.log(id);
});
```

But I have since found the problem is not quite as I stated it. If I click on `first`, then `second`, both clicks return "first". If I click on `second`, then on `first`, both return "second". Whichever fires first wins.

Comment: I converted your code to an executable snippet, it works fine.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual problem.

Comment: @Barmar: As I would expect! But something is messing it up, even on the minimal code I've since posted. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the debugger (Chrome DevTools).

I rebuilt the app from scratch. The jQuery was working when debugging was done using the console. However, inserting a breakpoint resulted in the output defaulting always to the first click on an input. Later clicks on either input always resulted in the ID of the first click.